# How to call Oracle's regexp_like function with Nhibernate QueryOver?

Tags: sql, regex, function, nhibernate, queryover

I'm aware I need to use Restrictions.Eq and Projections.SqlFunction, but I've been trying for hours without any success (my test app just crashes). Does anyone have an QueryOver example that would do the following in Oracle:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  V_LOG_ENTRIES
WHERE
  regexp_like(ENTRY_TEXT, '(\WPlaced\W)');
```

UPDATE: Okay, I think part of the problem is that Restrictions.Eq expects an equality, but there is no equality in this case, it's just a function call in the WHERE clause...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax should be like this:

```
// this is inlined string, but could be concatenated from some params
var sql = @" regexp_like(ENTRY_TEXT, '(\WPlaced\W)') " +
           " AS isLike";
var sqlString = new SqlString(sql);

// the ICriterion
var criterion = new NHibernate.Criterion.SQLCriterion(sqlString
    , new string[] {}
    , new IType[] {}
    );

// the query
var query = session.QueryOver<LogEntry>()
    .Where(criterion)
    ...
```

Comment: You're a live safer man, thanks! I'd up vote too, but seems I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Full examples of Oracle regex are hard to come by, +1. :)