# How to Specify a Constant Value NHibernate Criteria That Will Not Be Translated as an SQL Command Query Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate

I have an NHibernate query that uses the following clause:

```
Restrictions.EqProperty
(
    Projections.Property<Cat>(c => c.ByteProperty),
    Projections.Constant(CatBytePropertyValues.Value1)
)
```

This restriction is converted to a query parameter similar to the following

```
execute sp_executesql N'.... where c_.ByteProperty = @p0', N'@p0 tinyint', @p0=1...
```

For the specific query of interest, in order to take advantage of an index which has a filter on the above property, we would like the value '1' to be hard-coded, rather than explicitly parameterized, within the resultant SQL command.

For example, the following is what we would like to see

```
execute sp_executesql N'.... where c_.ByteProperty = 1'...
```

The root of this query is declared as a QueryOver. Something that would work with the the existing query would be what  is sought as the answer, although any such solution in any NHibernate api would definitely be marked as helpful.

Thank you all very much for all comments and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer here is `Projections.SqlProjection`

```
Restrictions.EqProperty
(
    Projections.Property<Cat>(c => c.ByteProperty),
    Projections.SqlProjection("1 as one", new string[] {} , new IType[] {})
)
```

this will generate inline SQL Statement without @parameter. Also check this *(as an example)* for a way how to use **custom SQL Criterions**:

- [How to call Oracle's regexp_like function with Nhibernate QueryOver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782474/)